# How can I store the same id number with different values in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a function "link". It has 3 input parameters i, x, y. My problem is if the input i is the same number as i that already exists in the array ix, it replaces the value of existing x and y by the new input values of x and y for I. and when printing it out it shows the last input values.

so what I want is to store it in ix array and print it out with the same i but different x or y values. (i.e. i is input twice, i is same, but value x or y is different).  How can I do this in C++? Any help would be appreciated.

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 void link(int i, int x, int y){
      
      ix[i][0]=x;
      ix[i][1]=y;
 }

 int main(){

   int i, x, y;
   int ix[5][2];

   for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
      cin>>i;       // if 5 input i= 1,2,3,3,4
      cin>>x;       // if 5 input x= 5,4,6,0,2
      cin>>y;       // if 5 input y= 9,0,7,7,3

      link(i,x,y);
   }

   for(int k=0;k<5;k++){  //it should output the same i but different x or y values
      cout<<ix[k][0];
      cout<<ix[k][1];
   }
  
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stop C style coding and learn C++. After you get an idea about objects with constructors you can learn about STL containers which can store such objects. std::multimap will be your friend in your case.

Comment: In this case, your array is just the wrong choice. Assuming, you replace your (C style) array by a `std::vector<>`, this could look like `std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>>`. (Please, note that I used `std::pair` to store x, y.) And, please, don't forget that you have to grant sufficient size for your `vector` before you can access an index. This can be done with 
 e.g. `std::vector::resize()`.

Comment: A `std::map<K,T>`?

Comment: `link` function cannot access the local `ix` in `main` in the way that it is attempting to do.  This code does not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array being used is the wrong kind of container for the data involved.  A `std::multimap` is a better choice.  Another alternative would be a vector that holds a `std::pair<int, Data>` (using the struct Data from below).

In the code example, the `struct Data` could also be represented as a `std::pair<int, int>`.

The example below also converts the code to be more idiomatic C++ and less C-style C++.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::istream;
using std::multimap;
using std::ostream;
using std::size_t;
using std::stringstream;

namespace {

char const* input_text =
R"(1 5 9
2 4 0
3 6 7
3 0 7
4 2 3)";

struct Data {
    int x;
    int y;
};

auto operator>>(istream& in, Data& d) -> istream& {
    in >> d.x >> d.y;
    return in;
}

auto operator<<(ostream& out, Data const& d) -> ostream& {
    out << d.x << " " << d.y;
    return out;
}

void print(ostream& out, multimap<int, Data> const& mm, int key, size_t nth) {
    auto range = mm.equal_range(key);
    size_t pos = 0;
    for (auto i = range.first; i != range.second; ++i) {
        if (pos++ == nth) {
            out << "key:" << key << " nth:" << nth << " Data:" << i->second << "\n";
            return;
        }
    }

    out << "key:" << key << " nth:" << nth << " Data not found\n";
}

} // anon

int main() {
    auto mm = multimap<int, Data>{};
    auto ss = stringstream(input_text);

    int i;
    Data data;
    while (ss >> i >> data) {
        mm.insert({i, data});
    }

    for (auto const& e : mm) {
        cout << e.first << ": " << e.second << "\n";
    }

    print(cout, mm, 1, 0);
    print(cout, mm, 3, 0);
    print(cout, mm, 2, 0);
    print(cout, mm, 3, 1);
    print(cout, mm, 5, 0);
}
```

UPDATE: added example of printing out the *n*th item of a specific key.

Comment: thank you. it works well. 
but if in case I just want to print out some selected element values not all elements in the multimap.
let's say, I want to print out the mapped value of unsorted key 1,3,2,3. (i.e. the first key #3 calls the first mapped value of 3, and the second key #3 calls the second mapped value of 3 ). how can i get this done?

Comment: @Kelly • You'll want to use multimap [`equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range) to find the range of elements by key, then iterate over it to find the *n*th element.

Comment: would you mind showing me in your example code?

Comment: @Kelly • done, I've updated the example code.

Comment: it works pretty fine. thank you very much